# Simple OpenCV program crashes

Tags: 14.04, qt5, opencv

I am currently having a problem. I am following the instructions given in this book "OpenCV 2 Computer Vison Application Programming Cookbook" for creating a simple image display program in OpenCV (2.4.10-1) using Qt(5.4), QtCreator in Ubuntu 14.04.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // read an image
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("${PATH_TO_HOME}/Pictures/bottle_label.jpg");

    if ( image.data == NULL )    {
        std::cout << "no data loaded" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        // create image window named "My image"
        cv::namedWindow("My Image", 1);
        // show the image on window
        std::cout << "Image loaded" << std::endl;
        cv::imshow("My Image", image);
        // wait key for 5000 ms
        cv::waitKey(5000);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

And the contents in the .pro file are

```
# Standard .pro content for qt console application #
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/

LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib \
        -lopencv_core  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d
```

The code compiles, but when I run it the program crashes immediately. The debuger points a SIGSEGV occurring in line 17:         `cv::namedWindow("My Image", 1)`
I don't know what to do. I have other programs that use qt and opencv libraries in the same computer but used cmake to build them and they run fine. Could someone please point out where the problem is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a question about Ubuntu: you should at least give details about exactly how you built and installed the opencv libraries (which I assume you did, given the `-L /usr/local/lib` library path). Have you tried building manually from the command line using something like `g++ -Wall -o your_prog your_prog.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)`?

Comment: @steeldriver Hi, here is the information request. (In cmake build directory)
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_CUBLAS=ON -D WITH_CUFFT=ON -D WITH_EIGEN=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_DOCS=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_TESTS=ON -D CUDA_ARCH_BIN="3.0" ..
I initially had opencv-2.4.8 in my machine allong with qt4. Then I deinstalled opencv-2.4.8 and installed CUDA 6.5, qt5 and opencv 2.4.10-1.